# what kind of encryption does this look like?

Tags: encryption, deobfuscation

I'm having a puzzle contest with my friends, and I'm stuck on this problem:

Does anyone know off the top of their head what kind of encryption this looks like? I'm really not expecting a spot on answer, but I **think** i ruled out caesar style cyphers, and I'm wondering if anyone can recognize this kind of encryption (if it helps at all, I think it was generated from a website's email address obfuscator).

```
%61%72%40%67%6f%6f%67%6c%65%6d%61%69%6c%2e%63%6f%6d%5c%22%3e%74%69%6d%75%72%2e%61%73%61%72%40%67%6f%6f%67%6c%65
```

Thanks for your help (and sorry for the possibly stupid question)!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That string looks like URL encoded characters to me. I threw it into a converter and got this result which looks less gibberish than I was expecting.

```
   ar@googlemail.com\">timur.asar@google
```

Does that mean anything to you?

Comment: Yeah it does haha, it goes with another part of the puzzle. Thanks!... You wouldnt happen to have the url of that converter, would you?

Comment: Yes. http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm  Scroll to bottom. Enter obfuscated text and use option on right to de-obfuscate.